# What files in google chrome are responsible for storing data of websites?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently, my friend on one of websites got ban. But when he visited this web site using another browser, every thing was ok. Now, as junior web developper, I'm trying to understad what file is responsible (in Chrome) for getting know to th website about ban. What is exact path of files?

Any idea?

Comment: AFAIK, "storage" permission must be declared in the [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) to use the [`chrome.storage API`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), This API is to be used to store, retrieve and track changes to user data. As for exact file paths, see this [page](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) and this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n-7S2pMX49c) for additional insights. Hope that helps.

Comment: comment above is unrlated because question is not about extensions.